# Is it code to create a return vent that goes directly to a furnace room from the floor above

Tags: hvac, ducts

My first-floor apartment (in a townhouse/brownstone) didn't have a return air duct installed and is instead just sucking in air from the boiler room with a large open return.  The architectural plans had transfer grills from the first floor into the basement hallway and mechanical room (with a fire-rated return vent) but these were never installed.

The ductwork in the basement ceiling is pretty congested with pipes, ducts, and gas lines so there are only a few simple areas where I can just punch a hole above near the blower to the first-floor hallway making a return.  The ideal spot looks to be creating a return channel in the linen closet wall on the ground floor right above the HVAC unit.  The vent would be in the wall facing into the hallway.

Looking for simple solutions, I see that if I just use a stud cavity above the furnace, that will drop right down below to the HVAC return.

1. Is using a wall cavity and creating a return vent/grille right above the furnace room up to New York City building and firecode? Or do I need to run duct work and not use a wall cavity? The section I found in the code I couldn't understand was:

> Stud wall cavities and joist space plenums shall comply with the
> floor penetration protection requirements of the Building Code of New
> York State.

> Stud wall cavities and joist space plenums shall be
> isolated from adjacent concealed spaces by approved fireblocking as
> required in the Building Code of New York State.

https://up.codes/viewer/new_york/ny-mechanical-code-2020/chapter/6/duct-systems#602.3

2. Do I need to run a rigid duct from that supply vent down, or can I just leave it open - a ductless return transfer grille above the basement ceiling flowing cold air to the open plenum return below?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would check with your city, many homes did use the stud cavity in years past. In commercial we have to have fire dampers but residential I haven’t seen the isolation requirement below 3 floors. But I live in the Pacific north west also.